# FTP not working between servers, only in command line

Tags: command-line-interface, ftp

Hello I have a strange problem, I want to transfer files via ftp between two servers. 
When I transfer the files sing the client, it works fine, but when I use command line I get:
425 Can't open data connection.
When I use the command line from my computer it works fine. 
I configured Passive mode of the server to use ports 5000-5100, and opened them on both servers, in Inbound and Outbound sections.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

By "using the client" I assume you mean the Filezilla GUI client?  Is that set to use passive mode?  If you are using passive mode you need to also direct the command-line client to use passive mode.  The command-line client uses active mode by default.  Enter the following statement after you connect to the ftp server:

`ftp> QUOTE PASV`

So, the full conversation would be like

```
C:\> ftp ftp.mydomain.com  
[enter your login and password as necessary]  
ftp> QUOTE PASV  
ftp> GET somefile.txt  
ftp> BYE
```

Give that a shot and see if it works for you.